# Updating & Querying all elements in array >= X where X is variable fast

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Formally we are given an array with some initial values. Then we have 3 types of Queries :-

1. Point updates : Increment by 1 at a given position
2. Range Queries : To count number of elements>=x where x is taken as input
3. Range Updates : To decrement by 1 all elements>=x, where x is given as input.

N=10<sup>5</sup> , Q=10<sup>5</sup> (number of elements in array, number of Queries resp.)

I tried doing this with segment Tree but operations 2,3 can be worse than O(n) even as we don't know which 'range' is to be updated exactly so we may end up traversing whole of segment tree.

**NOTE :** I wish to clear that if we need to do all 3 operations in logarithmic Worst case  ,ie O(log n) ,cause only then we can do this fast , linear approach doesn't works as Q=10^5 n N=10^5 , so worst case could be O(n^2) ,ie 10^10 operation which is clearly not feasible.

Comment: 10^5 isn't that much... Just copy & sort the array, keep the max and min values and binary search for the pivot element greater or equal than x (that would work for 2 in O(lg n)), For 3, binary search the pivot element again and then swap the elements down, they shouldn't bubble that much; in the worst case 3 would be O(n)

Comment: @higuaro: you never have to bubble *any* items downward to maintain order in #3. Since you're only decrementing by 1, and you're modifying all the items >= to some value, the item before the first one you decrement must always be at least 1 less than the one your decrementing, so the decrement by 1 never forces a change in order. After the decrement, the smallest affected elements might be equal to the previous element, but can never be smaller than it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, as the item values are narrowed down by 1 is the pivot which bubbles up, not the items (I admit it, I wrote down a test to make it clear to myself xD), thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The fact that the number of queries is of the same order as the number of elements strongly suggests that the "correct" answer will involve some sort of amortization argument.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're talking about 10<sup>5</sup> items, and don't mention needing to add or remove items, it seems to me that the obvious data structure would be a simple sorted vector.

Operation complexities:

1. point update: O(1) + O(m) (where `m` is the number of subsequent elements equal to the value before the update).
2. Range query: O(log n) + O(m) (where `n` is start of range, `m` is elements in range).
3. Range update (same as range query).

It's a little difficult to be sure what "fast" means to you, but the fastest theoretically possible for 1 is O(1), so we're already within some constant factor of optimal.

For 2 and 3, even if we could do the find with constant complexity, we're pretty much stuck with O(m) for the update. Since Log<sub>2</sub>100000 = ~16.6, most of the time the O(m) term is going to dominate (i.e., the update part will involve as many operations as the search unless the given `x` is one of the last 17 items in the collection.

I doubt there's any point for this small of a collection, but if you might have to deal with a substantially larger collection and the items in the collection are reasonably predictably distributed, it might be worth considering doing an interpolating search instead of a binary search. With predictable distribution this reduces the expected number of comparisons to approximately O(log log n). In this case, that would be roughly 4 (but normally with a higher constant factor). This *might* be a win for 10<sup>5</sup> items, but then again it might not. If you might have to deal with a collection of (say) 10<sup>8</sup> items or more, it would be much more likely to be a substantial win.

Comment: O(m) is definatly SLOW . Given Q=10^5 ,this approach will take O(n^2) , so at worst case we will have 10^10 operations to do which is not feasible. We need to do ALL operations in Logarithmic time , ie O(log n) as worst case (And can be done because question expects us this solution :) )

Answer (score 0):

The following may not be optimal, but is the best I could think of tonight.

Let's start by trying to turn the problem sideways. Instead of a map from indices to values, let's consider a map from values to sets of indices. A point update now involves removing an index from one set and adding it to another. A range update involves either simply moving an index set from one value to another or taking the union of two index sets. A range query involves folding over the sets corresponding to the values in range. A quick peek at Wikipedia suggests a traditional [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find) is really great for set unions. Unfortunately, it's no good at all for removing an element from a set.

Fortunately, there is a newer data structure supporting [union-find with constant time deletion](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/Union-Find%20with%20Constant%20Time%20Deletions.pdf)! That takes care of both point updates and range updates quite naturally. Range queries, unfortunately, will require checking all array elements, even if very few elements are in range.

Comment: Thanks , this was something new for me :) But i suppose all 3 operations are still not reduced to O(log(n)), isn't it?

Comment: @Shikhar, I'm not an expert, so I don't know if such a thing is known. I'm just a math student.

Comment: @Shikhar, there is no way to reduce range queries to O(log n). Printing k elements will take at least O(k). The question is whether it's possible to get it down to that (or near that) while still supporting the other operations quickly.

Comment: We needn't print k elements....we simply need to print number of such elements >=x. Thats it ,so it can be done and this is what questions wants us to do :)

Comment: @Shikhar, well, you should've said that! You wrote "to print all elements >= x". You should have written "to print the *number* of elements >= x." That should be much easier!

Comment: I am really very much sorry. Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected ^_^

Comment: @Shikhar But query 3 has the same problem: decrementing `k` elements will take at least `O(k)`.

Comment: @Teepeemm, that's not necessarily the case. This is only *abstractly* an array. It can be represented some other way. I still haven't figured out the best way though.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Yes dfeuer reasoned it precisely correct :)